# Can I store a string from a TextField within a tableViewCell into an array and then use that array again to contemplate its strings in the Textfield?

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, storing-data, indexpath

I would like to store `UITextField.text` into an array and then fetch the strings into the cells with the text field where I typed in the text before.

I already tried to store the entered text into the array and that seems to work.

`goalsCellEntries` is the Array.

I use this function to change the values in the array and that seems to work because in the console the values of the array change! The function is linked to the TextField over "Editing Did End" Event:

```
 @IBAction func goalsTextChangeDidEnd(_ sender: UITextField) {

        if let indexPath = self.goalsTableView.indexPathForView(sender){
            goalsCellEntries[indexPath.row].text = sender.text!
            print(goalsCellEntries)
        }
    }
```

Then I call this function in the `cellForRowAt` function so that when ever a Cell is recycled the updated version of the array string is used:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if tableView == scheduleTableView {

                let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "scheduleCell", for: indexPath) as! scheduleTableViewCell

                cell.scheduleStartTimeField.text = scheduleCellEntries[indexPath.row].time01

                cell.scheduleEndTimeField.text = scheduleCellEntries[indexPath.row].time02

                cell.scheduleTextField.text = scheduleCellEntries[indexPath.row].text


            if scheduleCellEntries[indexPath.row].timeButtonState == false{
                cell.scheduleDateCheckBox.isSelected = false

            }else{
                cell.scheduleDateCheckBox.isSelected = true

            }

            if scheduleCellEntries[indexPath.row].textButtonState == false{
                cell.scheduleTextCheckBox.isSelected = false

            }else{
                cell.scheduleTextCheckBox.isSelected = true

            }

                return cell



        } else if tableView == goalsTableView {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "goalsCell", for: indexPath) as! goalsTableViewCell

            cell.goalsTextField.text = goalsCellEntries[indexPath.row].text
            goalsTextChangeDidEnd(cell.goalsTextField)


            if goalsCellEntries[indexPath.row].buttonState == false{
                cell.goalsCheckBox.isSelected = false

            }else{
                cell.goalsCheckBox.isSelected = true

            }

            if goalsCellEntries[indexPath.row].buttonState == false{
                cell.goalsCheckBox.isSelected = false

            }else{
                cell.goalsCheckBox.isSelected = true

            }



            return cell
        } else if tableView == toDoTableView {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "toDoCell", for: indexPath) as!toDoTableViewCell

            cell.toDoTextField.text = toDoCellEntries[indexPath.row].text


            if toDoCellEntries[indexPath.row].buttonState == false{
                cell.toDoCheckBox.isSelected = false

            }else{
                cell.toDoCheckBox.isSelected = true

            }

            if toDoCellEntries[indexPath.row].buttonState == false{
                cell.toDoCheckBox.isSelected = false

            }else{
                cell.toDoCheckBox.isSelected = true

            }

            return cell
        } else /*if tableView == motivationTableView*/ {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "motivationCell", for: indexPath) as! motivationTableViewCell
            cell.motivationImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "placeholderImage")
            cell.motivationTextField.text = "Write your Motivation here!"

            return cell
        }
    }
```

But when I scroll in the tableView and the cells get recycled, the `UITextField.text` goes back to default.

Comment: Can you post more of your cellForRowAt() method? Why are you calling goalsTextChangeDidEnd() in that method?

Comment: Because I want the text from the text field to be stored into the array when I finished the editing.

Comment: It sounds like you're doing this the wrong way around. cellForRowAt() should populate the cell with the values that are already in your data model. You should update your model when the user finishes editing, then call reloadData() on your tableview if needed, which will call cellForRowAt().

Comment: yes @onnoweb , but isn't my function ```goalsTextChangeDidEnd``` updating my data model (array)? I can see in the console that the values in the array change after I edit them in the text field. When I scroll though, the text in the textfield is set to the initiall text from the array.